# Get the number of execution id wise in toad for oracle

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, toad

Please help in extracting a data of number of executions against respective id
For e.g. I have temp1 table with data of id and DT where id is given in the form below :

SNGL~27321~SUBM~**28867**_17227~20170815.CSV.20170815113439
SNGL~27321~SUBM~**28867**_17227~20170815.CSV.20170815113439
SNGL~27321~SUBM~**29329**_17227~20170815.CSV.20170815113439

I need the result as below :

id    number of exec
28867  2
29329  1

The query is below:

```
select count(A.DT)
from temp1 a
where  A.id like '%28867%' 
and A.DT >= to_date( '01-Aug-2017','dd-MON-yyyy')
and A.DT < to_date('01-Sep-2017','dd-MON-yyyy')
```

The problem i am facing is to extract ids from the column of id using like operator.

Please help me to retrieve the result in **TOAD FOR ORACLE**

Answer (score 0):

You can use [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm) function, or a combination of [SUBSTR](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions162.htm) and [INSTR](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_1103.htm#OLADM564) functions to extract this number from the string.
The latter is faster than the pattern matching in REGEXP_REPLACE, so if there is a huge table of strings I would use the second option. 
Assumming that `SUBM~` substring **is always** before the number, this should work:

```
With my_data as (

select 'SNGL~27321~SUBM~28867_17227~20170815.CSV.20170815113439' as str from dual union all
select 'SNGL~27321~SUBM~28867_17227~20170815.CSV.20170815113439' from dual union all 
select 'SNGL~27321~SUBM~29329_17227~20170815.CSV.20170815113439' from dual

)

SELECT
       regexp_replace( str, '.*SUBM~(\d+).*', '\1' ) as x,

       substr( str, 
               instr( str, 'SUBM~' ) + length('SUBM~'),
               instr( str, '_', instr( str, 'SUBM~' ) )
                - instr( str, 'SUBM~' ) 
                - length('SUBM~')
             ) as y

FROM My_data;
```

---

```
|     X |     Y |
|-------|-------|
| 28867 | 28867 |
| 28867 | 28867 |
| 29329 | 29329 |
```